# MS-ACCESS 2016 Main form and sub form complication

Tags: database, ms-access, normalization, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I've been trying to create a simple database with complex relationships; however, I am concerned about my table relationships and their normalization.

The basic premise is for users to data-entry information concerning Course Books we use at our institution.

The problem is, however, I'm having difficulty creating a main form that holds the multiple sub forms to enter the data effectively. There are a few problems that I have concerning this, and they are as follows:

1. I am concerned about the which control/row source properties to use for both the main form, and sub forms. I can get most of the information populated, up until SkillFocus and BkUntSctSkillFocus junction tables. I can get the separate subforms related to the SkillFocus junction table to populate, but the subformID's do not populate with the associated SkillFocus IDfk's.
2. All the data that I enter does not remain populated within the main/subform views when I navigate away (exit) from the subform objects. In order to have a consistent entry form, I would like all the data to be available for the user as it relates to the table strings. (e.g. CourseBook / Unit / Unit Name / Section / Skill Focus, etc.)

If I am able to effectively enter these book details, it would be a major milestone towards completing my project :D

[Link to image and database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-juuORLTO4kU05zNUlBVkJWLUE)

Comment: Edit: The main form is "Primary Book Details Extended"

Comment: You can edit your question.